# Setting the default value of an ng-bootstrap field (ngModels can't use getter/setter)

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, ng-bootstrap

I'm using an [ng-boostrap datepicker](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker) field in one of my forms and I'd like to initialize it with a default value.

In a "standard" form, I can use either `formControlName` or `ngModel` and it works fine:

```html
<!-- formControlName -->
<input ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" formControlName="dateFieldName">
<!-- ngModel -->
<input ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" [(ngModel)]="myDateProp">
```

My problem is I have wrapped the datepicker in my own custom field, i.e. a custom component implementing `ControlValueAccessor`.

In this scenario, **the datepicker is no longer aware of its parent form and the corresponding model**. So how can I initialize the datepicker field?

- `formControlName` is not an option (my custom field component doesn't and shouldn't have access to the model of its parent form).
- `ngModel` seemed easier since it's just a binding to a local property but my entire form freezes as soon as I add the `[(ngModel)]` directive to the datepicker field.

Here's the code for my custom field component so far:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'field-datetime',
  template: `
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
      <div class="input-group-addon" (click)="d.toggle()" >
        <i class="fa fa-calendar" style="cursor: pointer;"></i>
      </div>
    </div>`,
  providers: [
    { provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: forwardRef(() => FieldDateTimeComponent), multi: true }
  ]
})
export class FieldDateTimeComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  private _dateTimeObj: DateTime;  // Date is stored as an object internally

  propagateChange = (_: any) => {};

  // Write a new value to the element (from the form model into the view).
  writeValue(timestamp: number) {
    // Parse the timestamp to store it as an object internally.
    this._dateTimeObj = moment(timestamp).toObject();
    this.propagateChange(this._dateTimeObj);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any) {}

  // This is the property I'd like to bind to the field, i.e.:
  // <input ngbDatepicker [(ngModel)]="dateObj">
  // THIS IS WRONG. DO NOT USE A GETTER FOR A NGMODEL. SEE ANSWER BELOW.
  get dateObj() {
    return {day: this._dateTimeObj.date, month: this._dateTimeObj.months, year: this._dateTimeObj.years};
  }

}
```

Comment: [(ngModel)] is the right solution. Could you add some code? As a wild guess I can think of an infinite loop somewhere in your ControlValueAccessor implementation, like writeValue calling a setter, which calls writeValue back, or something of that sort.

Comment: @VincentV. Thanks for your time. I have updated the question with some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh... The problem was the use of a getter/setter for the ngModel (and had nothing to do with ng-bootstrap).

In other words, given this field in a template:

```html
<input name="foo" [(ngModel)]="foo">
```

The `foo` property CANNOT use a getter/setter in the class:

```ts
export class MyComp() {
  private _foo;
  get foo() {
    return this._foo;
  }
  set foo(val) {
    this._foo = val;
  }
}
```

But in order to still be able to react to model changes (which was the whole point of using a getter/setter in the first place), I had to rewrite the `ngModel` directive to use its expanded form:

```html
<input name="foo" [ngModel]="foo" (ngModelChange)="onFooChanged($event)">
```

Now `onFooChanged()` lets me `propagateChange` from my custom field to the parent form (just like the setter would have let me).

(In my original example, `get dateObj()` was the problem. Replacing it with a standard class property + using the syntax above fixed it.)

Answer (score 1):

The right solution is clearly the use of `[(ngModel)]` . Your real problem is the freeze when you try using it.

I think the problem is with calling the propagateChanges within writeValue, which triggers an infinite loop. 
Try the following:

html:

```
<input class="form-control" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" (change)="handleChange()" [(ngModel)]="_dateTimeObj">
```

ts:

```
writeValue(timestamp: number) {
  // Parse the timestamp to store it as an object internally.
  this._dateTimeObj = moment(timestamp).toObject();
}
handleChange($event) { 
  // manage sending the value back from the input to your model using $event.target.value
  this.propagateChange(this._dateTimeObj);
}
```

Comment: Turns out the problem was the use of a getter for the ngModel. I replaced it with a standard class property and it works. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, though. Without your comment I would have given up on ngModel.

Comment: You could almost express your gratitude with an upvote, then :p